# Display mysql results in javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

This is an javascript array where you put images and their are displayed:

```
    orakuploader_attach_images: ['cat.jpg', 'dolphin.jpg', 'lion.jpg'],
```

Now i have a database where I want to grab the images from database and want to add them to this array somehow. 
So how can I fetch the names from the database and put them in this array so they are displayed properly?

Any ideas?

Comment: use json to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
orakuploader_attach_images.push("fourth.jpg");
```

---

Or you can include a php file by:

```
var orakupload_attach_images = <?php include(array_image.php); ?>
```

The file `array_image.php` will have the array of images from your database:

```
echo json_encode(array('cat.jpg', 'dolphin.jpg', 'lion.jpg'));
```

---

Or call them by Ajax:

```
$.get( "array_image.php", function( data ) {
    var orakupload_attach_images = data;
    /* DO THE REST OF YOUR ACTION HERE */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
    orakuploader_attach_images: [
    <?php while($e=$get_photos_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) 
    {
          echo "'".$e['photo_name']."',";

    }
    ?>],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = <?php echo count($phpArr); ?>
var jsArr= <?php echo json_encode($phpArr); ?>;    

for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    console.log(jsArr[i]);
}
```